# Sorting of a table in MS Word doesn't seem to work

Tags: microsoft-word

I have this table in MS Word:

[image]

When I try to sort it by its second column:

[image]

Everything works fine:

[image]

However, if I add just one letter to the first and to the fourth lines of that column:

[image]

and try to run the same sorting, I receive the same table, that is, as if I never even tried to sort it:

[image]

In other words, the sorting function doesn't work when I add those letters.

Why does that happen?

I am using Windows XP and my "Word" file is a .docx file.

**EDIT**:

Here is the text copied from the table:

(lines 1 and 4):

```
Nouns in accusative preceded by preposition “on” and used with vE
```

(lines 2 and 3):

```
Nouns in accusative preceded by preposition “on” and used with verbs of motion: feminine nouns
```

Comment: how about create a new table, and paste the data, then work on it. Rather that working on the same original table.

Comment: @p._phidot_ - Just tried. The result is still the same  :(

Comment: sorry, couldn't help it.. : |

Comment: Would you mind sending the original text for each line? Also, what is your windows language setting and what is the proofing language of the style applied to your text?

Comment: @Ring: "Would you mind sending the original text for each line?" - My picture in the question shows the original text. I will still add the copied text to the question. "Also, what is your windows language setting and what is the proofing language of the style applied to your text?" - Can you, please, tell me how I could get this info from my computer?

Comment: I reproduced your problem on Word 2016. In my opinion you have hit a Word bug and could report it via File > Feedback (but don't hope for too much).

Comment: @harrymc: "I reproduced your problem on Word 2016" - Did it still persist in your case?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean, but the problem is still there and totally reproductible: Take out the "E" and the table is sortable, add it back in and the table doesn't sort. I have found many posts about unsortable tables but the only useful remark was that a header is needed for the table, but otherwise nothing useful.

Comment: After more experiments, this has something to do with the length of the text in the columns. It's enough to take out one word in the text with the "E", but leaving the "E", and the table becomes sortable. So the workaround is to shorten the text in the column if you want to sort the table. My tests show that it's perhaps enough to have short text only on the last row in the table, so perhaps a dummy last row will solve the problem.

Comment: @harrymc - "After more experiments, this has something to do with the length of the text" - But the text in lines 2 and 3 is much longer and yet sorting on them works fine.

Comment: @brilliant: Bugs are not features and do not behave logically. I cannot identify the bug with no access to the code source, but I have the feeling that it is triggered by some rows, perhaps even the last row, more than others.

Comment: use libreoffice. It's a bug in MS office

Comment: and stop using WinXP. You will face problems to which no resolution will ever be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Word.

Take out the "E" and the table is sortable, add it back in and the table doesn't sort.
Actually, it seems like taking out any one character in the text will enable
the sort.

Below is the table after the sort, when I took out the "a" of "accusative"
in the lines containing the "E":

[image]

So it seems that you need to make the text shorter to avoid the bug,
proceeding by trial and error to find the entry that causes the problem.
It might be related to the last row in the table, but this is not sure.

You can report the bug to Microsoft via menu *File > Feedback*
(but don't hope for an early resolution).